# Laravel Eloquent Model Give Me Error When I Tried to Use all() Function

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I created a `posts` table, and I used `php artisan make:model Post` to create a `Post` model.

php artisan make:migration create_posts_table --create="posts"

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //
}
```

When I tried to get all records using model::all()...

```php
route::get('/find', function (){
    return var_dump(App\Post::all());
});
```

It always gives me this error.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Unsupported operand types.

Can someone please help me?

The problem is caused by App\Post::all() but I dont know why

Comment: Please include your migration for `posts`.

Comment: 2 things. **1:** Why are you echoing the `var_dump()`? **2.** How can you expect `Post::all()` to give `Post` table results without mentioning table name in the model?

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27052.

Comment: The error shown simply because of you try to echo a array, it's is not possible. echo only support string. you just do var_dump() for debug your result.

Comment: use dd(\App\Post::all())

Comment: Don't even use dd... A return from a route or controller will be returned as json. As for the error no idea, you are extending the model. Did you run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: @MichaelMano Yes I did

Comment: show your migration table please? It don't have a problem if you created model with table and migrated all of them.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir you save my day!!!!!!!!!!! I revert my laravel version from 5.7 to 5.6. It resloved!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug concerning Xdebug when using PHP 7.3 or 7.3.1 with Laravel 5.7.

Temporary workarounds include:

```
- Disable php-xdebug on PHP 7.3.0*
- Disable OPCache (opcache.enable=0 on php.ini, then restart PHP services) 
- Set opcache.optimization_level=0x7FFFBBFF
```

More info here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27030

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jonas Staudenmeir' comment. This is the problem with laravel version 5.7. And it has not been fixed yet

I reinstall laravel 5.5, it works perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

initialize you table name into your model ....

```
class Post extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'posts';
}

route::get('/find', function (){
return dd(\App\Post::all());
});
```